# Data Table column sorting not working server side Spring MVC

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, spring, spring-mvc

I am fetching some data and showing in a table. Here I am using data table. Everything is working fine but not able to sorting data by clicking the column heading of data table. I am not able to understand what is the issue. please help me to find the solution. My HTML, Javascript and Server side code written below:

```
<div class="widget-body no-padding table-responsive">       
    <table id="manage_quote" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" width="100%">
        <thead>                         
            <tr>
                <th data-hide="phone">Id</th>
                <th data-class="expand"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-user text-muted hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-xs"></i>User Name</th>
                <th data-class="expand"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-user text-muted hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-xs"></i> Agent Name</th>
                <th data-hide="phone,tablet"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-calendar txt-color-blue hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-xs"></i> Created On</th>
                <th data-hide="phone,tablet">Status</th>        
                <th data-hide="phone,tablet">Action</th>                                
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {

    var table = $('#manage_quote').dataTable({
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": "/common/getDetails",
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bSort": true,
        "pageLength" : 10,
        language: {
            paginate: {
              next: '&#8594;', // or 'â'
              previous: '&#8592;' // or 'â' 
            }
          }
    }); 

});
</script>
```

**Spring Controller Class**

```
@RequestMapping(value="/common/getDetails")
    public void manageAdvisorDetails(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
    {   
        try
        {           
            HashMap<String, String> userMap = (HashMap<String, String>) request.getSession().getAttribute("userMap");
            if(userMap != null && userMap.get("user_type").equalsIgnoreCase(Utils.ADMIN))
            {
               System.out.println("calling");
               String sEcho = request.getParameter("sEcho");
               String sSearch = request.getParameter("sSearch");
               String sColumns = request.getParameter("sColumns");
               String iDisplayStart = request.getParameter("iDisplayStart");
               String iDisplayLength = request.getParameter("iDisplayLength");
               String iColumns = request.getParameter("iColumns");  

               String iTotalRecords = "";
               String iTotalDisplayRecords = "";
               JsonArray data = new JsonArray();

               ManageDetails manageUsersResponse = commonDAO.getDetails( sSearch, iDisplayStart, iDisplayLength);        

               iTotalRecords = manageUsersResponse.getNoOfTotalRecords();
               iTotalDisplayRecords = manageUsersResponse.getNoOfRecords();



               List<Quote> quoteList  = manageUsersResponse.getQuoteList();

               for (Quote quote : quoteList) 
               {
                    System.out.println(quote.getId());
                    System.out.println(quote.getFirst_name());
                    System.out.println(quote.getLast_name());
                    System.out.println(quote.getAgent_name());

                    JsonArray row = new JsonArray();                
                    row.add(new JsonPrimitive(quote.getId()));
                    row.add(new JsonPrimitive(quote.getFirst_name() + " " + quote.getLast_name()));                             
                    row.add(new JsonPrimitive(quote.getAgent_name()));
                    row.add(new JsonPrimitive(quote.getQuote_date().toString()));                   
                    if(quote.getPayment_status().equalsIgnoreCase(Utils.PAYMENT_COMPLETE))
                    {
                        String html = "<a href='/admin?id=" + quote.getId() + "' ><span class='text-success' aria-hidden='true'>" + quote.getPayment_status() + "</span></a>";
                        row.add(html);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        String html = "<a href='/admin?id=" + quote.getId() + "' ><span class='text-info' aria-hidden='true'>" + quote.getPayment_status() + "</span></a>";
                        row.add(html);
                    }

                   row.add(new JsonPrimitive("<a href='/admin/getClientDetails?id=" + quote.getId() + "'><span class='btn btn-xs btn-success'>View</span></a>"));

                    data.add(row);
               }

                Gson gson = new Gson();        
                JsonObject jsonResponse = new JsonObject();

                jsonResponse.addProperty("sEcho", sEcho);
                jsonResponse.addProperty("iTotalRecords", iTotalRecords);
                jsonResponse.addProperty("iTotalDisplayRecords", iTotalDisplayRecords);
                jsonResponse.add("aaData", gson.toJsonTree(data));

                response.setContentType("application/Json");
                response.getWriter().print(jsonResponse.toString());
            }
            else
            {

            }           
        }
        catch (Exception ex) 
        {           
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

**Spring DAO Class**

```
public static ManageDetails getQuotes(String searchTerm,String iDisplayStart, String iDisplayLength)
    {       
        Session session = null;
        ManageDetails ManageDetails = null;
        UserDetails userdetails = null;
        List<UserDetails> quoteList = null;
        try
        {
            ManageDetails = new ManageDetails();
            session = HibernateUtils.getSession();
            session.getTransaction().begin();

            String query_noOfTotalRecords = "select count(*) from UserDetails";
            String query_str = "from UserDetails ";

            int noOfRecordsPerPage = Integer.parseInt(iDisplayLength);
            int startIndex = Integer.parseInt(iDisplayStart);
            int endIndex = startIndex + noOfRecordsPerPage;

            if (searchTerm !=null && !searchTerm.equalsIgnoreCase("")){
                query_str+=" where (id like '%"+searchTerm+"%'";
                query_str+=" or first_name like '%"+searchTerm+"%'";
                query_str+=" or last_name like '%"+searchTerm+"%'";
                query_str+=" or agent_name like '%"+searchTerm+"%'";
                query_str+=" or title like '%"+searchTerm+"%')";
            }
            query_str+=" order by id desc";

            Query query = session.createQuery(query_str);
            query.setFirstResult(startIndex);
            query.setMaxResults(noOfRecordsPerPage);
            Integer noOfRecords = ((Long)session.createQuery("select count(*) " + query_str).uniqueResult()).intValue();
            quoteList = query.getResultList();
            int noOfPages = noOfRecords / 20;
            int reminderRecords = noOfRecords%20;

            if(noOfPages == 0)
            {
                    noOfPages = 1;
            }
            if(reminderRecords > 0 && noOfRecords > 20)
            {
                    noOfPages++;
            }

            ManageDetails.setQuoteList(quoteList);
            ManageDetails.setNoOfPages(String.valueOf(noOfPages));
            ManageDetails.setNoOfRecords(String.valueOf(noOfRecords));
            ManageDetails.setPageId(String.valueOf(""));
            ManageDetails.setNoOfTotalRecords(String.valueOf(session.createQuery(query_noOfTotalRecords).uniqueResult()));

            session.getTransaction().commit();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            session.getTransaction().rollback();
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return ManageDetails;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have permanent sort by Id statically set in the

```
query_str+=" order by id desc";
```

You need to pass sort column from your jQuery call, get the sort on server side, pass to the DAO and use it in the `order by`.

By the way your DAO has SQL injection vulnerability. Use params rather than concat SQL query string.